# Confluence wiki format put new paragraph

Tags: confluence, confluence-rest-api

I'd like to put empty linespace (`<p></p>` in HTML) in Confluence wiki result, but failed whatever I tried.

Based on the [the document](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/confluence-storage-format-790796544.html), it said two carriage-return will put `<p></p>` but `\r\r`, `\n\n`, `\n\n\n\n`, etc.trials are not working at all.

POST http://wiki.mysite.com/rest/api/content

```
{"type":"page","title":"new page1","ancestors":[{"id":390668024}], "space":{"key":"EXAMPLE"},"body":{"storage":{"value":"[Some link|http://example.com/url] - Show page.\n\nbq. Query by [Some link info|http://example.com/reference?id=214]","representation":"wiki"}}}
```

With above REST request, I'd like to show as below format;

[Some link](http://example.com/url) - Show page.

`<blank line>`

> Query by [Some link info](http://example.com/reference?id=214)

Some trials (between words `Show page.` and `bq. Query by`)

- `\n\n` => `Show page.</p>\n\n<blockquote><p>Query by`
- `\\\\` => `Show page. <br class=\"atl-forced-newline\" /> bq. Query by`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below trial gives expected result

`Show page.\n\n \\\\ \nbq. Query by`

=> `Show page.</p>\n\n<p> <br class=\"atl-forced-newline\" /> </p>\n<blockquote><p>Query by`